# Consumindo webservice por procedure SQL Server?

Tags: json, sql-server, web-service, stored-procedures

Estou usando o sql server 2016 para consumir webservice por store procedure. Tenho um webservice em JSON retornando o seguinte:

```
[{"nome":"Rebecca","email":"rebecca@hotmail.com","ra":"12345"},{"nome":"Caroline","email":"caroline@hotmail.com","ra":"23456"},{"nome":"Vanessa","email":"vanessa@yahoo.com.br","ra":"99999"}]
```

Consigo consumi-lo passando uma variável. Se eu deixar meu webservice para receber um parametro e passa-lo eu consigo retornar nome e email do aluno. Porém se eu deixar meu webservice sem a necessidade de receber parametro e retirar a passagem de parametro da procedure e executar, minha procedure retorna null. O que eu preciso mudar no meu código para conseguir retornar a lista completa de alunos que meu webservice expoe?

Segue meu código com passagem de parametros que retorna o usuário do RA correspondente:

```
create PROCEDURE webservice_parametros (@RA as varchar (5))
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @OBJ INT;
DECLARE @URL VARCHAR(200);
DECLARE @RESPONSE VARCHAR(8000);

SET @URL = 'http://dominio:8080/v1/alunos/' + @RA
EXEC SP_OACREATE 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp', @OBJ out
EXEC SP_OAMETHOD @OBJ, 'OPEN', NULL, 'GET', @URL, FALSE
EXEC SP_OAMETHOD @OBJ, 'SEND'
exec SP_OAGETPROPERTY @OBJ, 'responseText', @RESPONSE out
EXEC SP_OADESTROY @OBJ

SELECT JSON_VALUE(@RESPONSE, '$.nome') as nome,
    JSON_VALUE(@RESPONSE, '$.email') as email

END     

execute webservice_parametros '12345'
```

**Editado**

Meu código que retorna null para um serviço que não precisa de parâmetros

```
create PROCEDURE webservice
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @OBJ INT;
DECLARE @URL VARCHAR(200);
DECLARE @RESPONSE VARCHAR(8000);

SET @URL = 'http://dominio:8080/v1/alunos/'
EXEC SP_OACREATE 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp', @OBJ out
EXEC SP_OAMETHOD @OBJ, 'OPEN', NULL, 'GET', @URL, FALSE
EXEC SP_OAMETHOD @OBJ, 'SEND'
exec SP_OAGETPROPERTY @OBJ, 'responseText', @RESPONSE out
EXEC SP_OADESTROY @OBJ

SELECT JSON_VALUE(@RESPONSE, '$.nome') as nome,
    JSON_VALUE(@RESPONSE, '$.email') as email

END     

execute webservice
```

**Editado**

Aqui um web service público que testei e retornou nulo da mesma forma.

`http://ws.sistemaindustria.org.br/api-basi/v1/entidades/3/departamentos.json`

Comment: Você tem esse serviço de uma maneira pública para que possamos testar o acesso?

Comment: @Sorack não ele está só interno no momento pois está em desenvolvimento ainda. Mas é aberto, não tem autenticação nenhuma e quando chamo ele no browser retorna o resultado passado na pergunta.

Comment: @Marconi o que eu preciso de verdade é retornar a lista completa sem passagem de parametros nenhum. Parametros eu coloquei só pra testar o retorno mesmo e caso seja necessário para outro webservice. Mas se der pra fazer as duas coisas numa mesma proc, melhor.

Comment: Sem saber a URL correta e se ela realmente retorna algum resultado fica muito difícil de ajudar

Comment: @Sorack eu publiquei na pergunta o resultado do webservice. Eu já sei que retorna e testei isso com a passagem de parametros. O que eu preciso é saber o que mudar no código para exibir a lista completa sem precisar passar qualquer parametro.

Comment: Aparentemente seu problema não é na chamada e sim no serviço que não está preparado para retornar sem parâmetros

Comment: Eu tenho os dois serviços. Para receber passagem de parametro e sem passagem de parametro.

Comment: Coloquei na pergunta um webservice com a saída exatamente igual a do meu que eu testei e deu o mesmo resultado: `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

Segue resposta:

```
DECLARE @OBJ INT;
DECLARE @URL VARCHAR(200);
DECLARE @RESPONSE VARCHAR(8000);

CREATE TABLE #xml (
Ds_Dados VARCHAR(MAX)
)

SET @URL = 'http://ws.sistemaindustria.org.br/api-basi/v1/entidades/3/departamentos.json'
EXEC SP_OACREATE 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp', @OBJ out
EXEC SP_OAMETHOD @OBJ, 'OPEN', NULL, 'GET', @URL, FALSE
EXEC SP_OAMETHOD @OBJ, 'SEND'
insert into #xml
exec SP_OAGETPROPERTY @OBJ, 'responseText'
EXEC SP_OADESTROY @OBJ

select * from #xml
```

Comment: Poderia editar a resposta e explicar os detalhes ( o que o autor estava errando ) ? Assim se faz melhor a utilização do site, e ajuda outras pessoas a encontrarem solução para o problema. Para editar, abaixo da sua resposta tem as opções `[compartilhar editar sinalizar]` ou [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/243598/edit) ... [Da revisão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/134794).